# To manage or to use?

Tags: synonyms

I am writing a text in English and unfortunately word "use" is used very often (like in this statement:) ).

So I decided to replace it with other words where it is possible.

For example there is such expression in the text (it is about programming)

> to demonstrate his skill to use loops

Could it be replaced with the following expression?

> to demonstrate his skill to manage loops.

Do they have the same or at least close meanings?

Comment: They're close, but not identical. Look ip definition for "manage". It's not as wide and varied as definition for "use".   By the way, I would say "skill IN {using/managing} loops"

Comment: @Brian Hitchcock Does manage means in this context the ability to write loops without assistance? That is that the programmer demonstrates his solid skiils in using loops?

Comment: not sure. Writing loops seems different from "managing" or "using" loops. You "manage" or " use" something that already exists.  If you want to emphasize ability to create them properly, why not say "write"?

Comment: @Brian Hitchcock I want to express the idea that he not only knows how to write loops in general but also is able to build an appropriate loop for a particular task.:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are not identical. 
Why not go with "to demonstrate his skills in creating and manipulating loops".

Comment: It is a good idea and I asked exactly whether manage can be a synonim for creating and manipulatings loops can it?

Comment: Nope...manage would exclude the creating part

Comment: Does not manipulating of loops include creating of loops?

Comment: You are right!! Just manipulate should also work.

Comment: So may I write "to demonstrate his skill in managing loops"?

Comment: I do not think manage conveys the exact meaning, but in context it will work. However, if your target audience is layman, I would encourage you to be more specific.

Comment: The original statement looks the following way "the task of a beginner is to demonstrate his skill to use loops." Now I am going to replace it with "the task of a beginner is to demonstrate his skill in managing loops". Are they close in  meaning?

Comment: Yep. In this context, I would say they convey almost similar meaning